# How to detect a special character in password-string in python

Tags: python, if-statement

Im making a program where you can add password to the database. The password should contain one uppercase, one lowercase, one digit, one special character and should be between 8 and 30 characters. The rest works except for the special character part. I put a special character in the string but my program still tells me it has no special character. Im not sure what im doing wrong here:

```
specialCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;'<>,.?/"

def checkPassword(password):
    global specialCharacters
    errorString = ""
    if(len(password) < 8 or len(password) > 30):
        errorString = "ERROR: Your password must be between 8 and 30 characters"
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.isalpha() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least letter")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.isupper() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least one uppercase")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.islower() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least one lowercase")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.isdigit() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least one digit")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    for ch in password:                   /// here is the problem
        if ch not in specialCharacters:
            errorString = "ERROR: password must contain at least one special character"
            print(errorString)
            return False
    else:
        return True


checkPassword("Hellooooo1*") // returns "ERROR: password must contain at least one special character", why?
```

Comment: `len(set(password).intersection(specialCharacters)) >0`

Comment: `'H'` is not in `specialCharacters`. `'e'` is not in `specialCharacters`. `'l'` is not in `specialCharacters`....

Comment: @Epsi95 do I need to do this in an if statement?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hmm alright, i tried to switch the variabels password and specialCharacters in the for loop but still didnt solve it :(. It would then be "*" is not in 'Password'

Comment: You can use the method in the first comment or the similar: `len(set(specialCharacters) & set(password)) > 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're checking that each character in your password is ***not in*** the special characters - if any don't appear in that string, the if statement executes and the password is rejected.

To re-work this, you don't need an explicit loop for this and the [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) keyword can be used:

```
...
elif all(x not in specialCharacters for x in password):
    errorString = "ERROR: password must contain at least one special character"
    print(errorString)
    return False
return True
```

Comment: By this, all special characters should be present

Comment: @Sujay it requires at least one is present - all returns true if every element is True, False otherwise. For "a*" we have all([True, False])==False (accept password) and for "ab" we have all([True, True])==True (reject password).

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code. The last block where you check for the special character is checking only the first character and fails there. You need to loop through the complete string before making the judgment.

```
specialCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;'<>,.?/"

def checkPassword(password):
    global specialCharacters
    errorString = ""
    if(len(password) < 8 or len(password) > 30):
        errorString = "ERROR: Your password must be between 8 and 30 characters"
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.isalpha() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least letter")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.isupper() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least one uppercase")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.islower() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least one lowercase")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    elif(any(char.isdigit() for char in password) == False):
        errorString = ("ERROR: password must contain at least one digit")
        print(errorString)
        return False
    else:
        special_found = False
        for ch in password:                   
            if ch in specialCharacters:
                speical_found = True
        return speical_found

print(checkPassword("Hellooooo1*"))
```